# How to expand X axis to include arrows in stick plot (oce)

Tags: r, plot

I'm creating a stick plot using the "plotSticks" function in the oce library. The arrows that are created in the stick plot often go beyond the limits of the x axis. In my case, the x axis is usually a date range that I can't adjust to fit the data.

As you can see in this plot:

```
library(oce)
x<-1:10
u<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
v<-c(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3)
plotSticks(x,0,u,v)
```

The ends of the arrows go beyond the limits of my x axis. Is there a way to include some space on either side of the x axis so that the tips of the arrows can be seen?

The plotSticks has a yscale function that can reduce the size of the arrows, but then the arrows do not match the y axis scale so I'd like to avoid using the yscale fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this get you the result you want?  It extends the x axis and uses the yscale argument.

```
library(oce)
x<-1:10
u<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
v<-c(0,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3)
plotSticks(x,0,u,v, xlim=c(0, 40), ylim=c(-.5, 4), yscale=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The xlim argument worked. But is there a reason you chose to change the y scale to 2. I'm weary of altering the y scale for these plots as they seem to change the lengths of the arrows, without changing the range of the y axis. So if the y axis represents meters per second, if I change the yscale argument to something other than 1, I'm assuming I'm divorcing the arrows from the axis.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to see how to keep the rightmost arrows in the plot.  Even with the xlim argument at 100 that did not happen, so I experimented with the yscale argument.  In other words, without considering the real-world use case, I tried to achieve what you asked for.

Comment: Good point. For real-world use I'll keep the y scale set to 1.